# 5th chapter starts on even page

Tags: report

As stated in the title, a weird thing happens with the 5th chapter. All the previous chapters start on odd pages, but the 5th one starts on even number. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? I use this class for my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside,openright]{report}
\begin{document}

\include{chapters/Frontespizio}
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\include{chapters/Sommario}
\include{chapters/Ringraziamenti}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\include{chapters/Capitolo1}
\include{chapters/Capitolo2}
\include{chapters/Capitolo3}
\include{chapters/Capitolo4}
\include{chapters/Capitolo5}
\include{chapters/Conclusioni}
\pagenumbering{roman} 
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist, nogroupskip]
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, filter=bookorincollection]
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Sitografia}, nottype=book, nottype=incollection]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It shouldn't. Show us what you have done to make that happen.

Comment: It probably has something to do with redefining `\cleardoublepage`.

Comment: Thank you both for the reply @PeterWilson ! Added more info in the original post. It's weird because after the 4th chapters it adds two blank pages instead of one. In the table of contents the 5th chapter appears to start at page 87 (which is the second blank pages added), but in reality all the text appears at page 88. Chapter 6, which is the last one, starts on odd page again!

Comment: Your MWE uses files that we don't have. They could cause any number of problems. Basically we don't know what you have done, and I'm not prepared to guess. --- GOM

Comment: In the included file for the 5th chaptewr did you have anything before the `\chapter{...` command?